# How to load textures using SDL to a WebAssembly project using emscripten?

Tags: c++, emscripten, sdl-image, webassembly

I'm trying to load a texture to my application using SDL. When building as a native application, it works as it should. But when I'm building it with Emscripten, the texture cannot be loaded.

The width of the texture image is **64** pixels, which I can verify by printing out the `w` member of the SDL_Surface instance. But when I try to print out the same member in the WebAssembly application, it yields **5076**...

**Does the image become "broken" somehow when packed with emscripten?**

Here's the code to load the texture:

```
SDL_Surface *image = IMG_Load("resources/binaries/crate.jpg");
GLuint textureID;
glGenTextures(1, &textureID);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
std::cout << image->w << std::endl;
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, 64, 64, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image->pixels);
```

Here's the command to build the web app with Emscripten

```
emcc --bind -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o webapp.js src/webapp.cpp --preload-file resources
```

The error message I'm getting the browser when launching the web app is

> webapp.js:9533 WebGL: INVALID_VALUE: texImage2D: width or height out of range

Which makes sense, since the resolution of the image is so crazy...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out I had to use `--use-preload-plugins` when executing emcc to create the preload file. Finally, the command looks like this:

```
emcc --bind -s USE_SDL=2 -s USE_SDL_IMAGE=2 -o webapp.js src/webapp.cpp --preload-file resources --use-preload-plugins
```